# Python: is iter(x) equivalent to for el in x: yield el?

Tags: python, iterator

Suppose there is a collection:

```
list = [1,2,3]
```

is this builtin method

```
it1 = iter(list)
```

equivalent to

```
def niter(x):
    for el in x:
        yield el

it2 = niter(list)
```

**EDIT:** 
To further clarify, I know that `iter()` can except more arguments, but in principal I want to know if its the same as what yield is doing in `niter`

Comment: `iter` works on even Custom objects.

Comment: In principle they are the same.

Comment: This question is too vague: there are ways they are the same, and ways they are different.  How do we decide what you mean by "in principal"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `iter(lst)` returns a `list_iterator` object, the second example is a generic `generator`. Both do the same, but in different ways. `xxx_iterator` objects are aware of the structure they are iterating on, and use its specific properties to implement their `next` method. Generic generators don't know anything about their arguments (if any) and rely on them to implement the iterator protocol. So `iter(lst)` returns the *real* iterator, the one that actually fetches items from the list, and your `niter` is just a wrapper that merely delegates the job to its argument (which happens to be `list_iterator` once again).

In other words `iter(obj)` basically says "Dear obj, I need someone who knows how to iterate you" and `for z in obj` is "I don't care how to iterate you, just gimme values".

Comment: so if i generalize `niter(x): if type(x)=='list': do_something(x) elif type(x)=='tuple': do_something_else(x)`. etc it's behaviour is the same, right? I just wanted to understand if `iter` is doing a simple `yield` on custom objects.

Comment: @yayu: a custom object must implement iteration protocol (`__iter__`) or sequence protocol (`__getitem__`) in order to support `iter`. Otherwise you cannot iterate it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some minor differences, as @georg mentions, but I usually use `iter` in contexts where the underlying object does not support `next()`.

Answer (score 1):

No, `iter` and `niter` behave differently on objects that do not support the [iteration or sequence protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter):

```
In [12]: class Bar(object): pass

In [13]: niter(Bar())
Out[13]: <generator object niter at 0xa8f016c>

In [14]: iter(Bar())
TypeError: 'Bar' object is not iterable
```

Comment: That's not a major difference, it just means that `iter` does more checks than `niter`.

Comment: Accepting an argument and raising a TypeError is a huge difference!

Comment: I don't believe OP is trying to write a polyfill, he is trying to understand a concept.

Comment: This is actually the thing I dislike about generators: they act like time bombs when applied to non-iterables. The call succeeds and everything looks fine, but once you start looping it -- baaaang!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the documentation,

#### [`iterator`](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator)

> An object representing a stream of data. Repeated calls to the iterator’s `next()` method return successive items in the stream. When no more data are available a `StopIteration` exception is raised instead. At this point, the iterator object is exhausted and any further calls to its `next()` method just raise `StopIteration` again

#### [`generator`](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator)

> **A function which returns an *iterator*.** It looks like a normal function except that it contains `yield` statements for producing a series a values usable in a `for-loop` or that can be retrieved one at a time with the `next()` function.

[Also](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types),

> **Python’s generators provide a convenient way to implement the iterator protocol.** If a container object’s `__iter__()` method is implemented as a generator, it will automatically return an iterator object (technically, a generator object) supplying the `__iter__()` and `next()` methods.